# Updated Galaxy s3 and SD isn't recognized

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, sd-card

I recently updated the software on my phone and it works great!! It's lollipop 5.1.1 , the problem is that the phone doesn't recognize the sd card anymore and my computer doesn't recognize as a removable drive anymore. I just want to know with that being the problem is there a way to downgrade back the the old software? and how if I cant use the sd card?

Comment: I also have a Galaxy S3 and it has "eaten" two SD cards! The phone won't recognize the cards anymore and my computer doesn't recognize them either. Did you find any solution for this or are the cards just fried?

Answer (score -1):

There could be simple fixes that will allow you to keep your upgrade. With each new "flavor" of Android new APIs are released with relation to enhancements to the OS. Have you tried a brand new SD card? or backup and format for the current one?  Also a reinstall of the USB drivers may help. I hope you backed up your previous stock ROM because if not you will need to find one online(if possible). It will help if your device is rooted.  Good Luck!

Comment: There is lack of info from OP, but reinstalling drivers wouldn't make an SD card popup in my computer as removable drive since 4.4+ and 5.0+ devices doesn't have "USB Mass storage" support.

Comment: I was under the impression that the host device (computer) was not recognizing the tablet. Suggested the reinstall of drivers as maybe a way to get to MTP due to the upgrade.